# How to use a CROSS JOIN to recursively generate permutations in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to use use CROSS JOINs in a recursive CTE to generate permutations. However, when I run the following code:

```
WITH RECURSIVE permute (n) AS (
    SELECT ARRAY[a.*, b.*] FROM unnest(ARRAY[ARRAY[1], ARRAY[2], ARRAY[3]]) a
    CROSS JOIN unnest(ARRAY[1, 2, 3]) b
UNION ALL
    SELECT ARRAY[a.n, ARRAY[b.*]] FROM unnest(ARRAY[1, 2, 3]) b
    CROSS JOIN permute a 
)
SELECT * FROM permute
```

which I would expect to infinitely generate combos. Instead, I just get the initial, non-recursive result:

```
"{1,1}"
"{1,2}"
"{1,3}"
"{2,1}"
"{2,2}"
"{2,3}"
"{3,1}"
"{3,2}"
"{3,3}"
```

Disappointing to say the least. I'd like to do this using CROSS JOIN in a recursive CTE, and I'm not sure exactly why my approach fails, or whether it could be modified to work. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That causes an error for me as expected, because you are trying to `UNION` scalars and arrays. Can you describe what you want to do (e.g., your desired result) some more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following generates permutations in arrays:

```
WITH RECURSIVE permute  AS (
      SELECT ARRAY[v.n] as ar, 1 as lev
      FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) v(n) 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT p.ar || v.n, lev + 1
      FROM permute p CROSS JOIN
           (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) v(n) 
      WHERE lev < 5
     )
SELECT p.ar
FROM (SELECT p.*, MAX(lev) OVER () as max_lev
      FROM permute p
     ) p
WHERE lev = max_lev;
```

Adjust the `5` for the number of permutations you want.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=ccc9a73ae439ca9bc0fc3585e12867b7) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense!